# Pace Js when "done" the body scrolls up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loading, pace.js

I'm using the lovely [pace.js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) as my page loader.

I created a `#cover` to hide all the content while the loading process complete.

```
#cover{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#000;
z-index:99999;
width:100%;
height:100%
}
```

All I want, when the loading is complete is the cover to scroll up and the content to follow. So the content will slide up from the bottom of the page.

This Javascript makes the cover scrolling up the problem is the second part = the body to follow from the bottom of the page

```
$(window).load(function() {
    Pace.on('done', function() {
    $("#cover").slideUp(700);
    });
});
```

This website is what I would like to achieve in terms of loading:
http://www.ok-rm.co.uk

Any help?
Thanks.

Fed.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach:

```js
$("body").on("click", function(){
 $(this).toggleClass("slideup")
});
```

```css
html, body {padding:0; margin:0; height:100%;}

#cover {
  position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:1;
  background:#000; color:#FFF;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  transition:.3s;
}

#body {
  transition:.3s;
  position: relative;
  top:100%;
}

body {overflow:hidden;} /* hide scrollbar by default */
body.slideup {overflow:auto;} /* show scrollbar after loading */
body.slideup #cover {top:-100%;} /* slide #cover up */
body.slideup #body {top:0;} /* slide #body up */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cover">Loading Content</div>

<div id="body">
  <h1>Hello Universe</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem autem dicta suscipit aliquam aperiam rerum libero id non nulla, voluptatibus, ullam omnis voluptatem ab amet ipsa. Alias deserunt magni tempore.</p>
  <p>Voluptate reiciendis in tempora repudiandae, repellat odit eligendi quis. Obcaecati voluptatem eveniet, maiores, dolore modi officiis nesciunt itaque. Perferendis odit porro aperiam, mollitia repudiandae cupiditate, alias ipsa architecto adipisci magni?</p>
  <p>Soluta minima officia provident beatae similique qui nam in facilis, quibusdam. Pariatur odio qui repellendus tenetur quae aperiam molestias eum exercitationem ipsa veniam, doloribus id temporibus doloremque, sapiente facere, cum.</p>
  <p>Inventore officia corporis cumque, eius id quam cupiditate tempora unde, beatae ipsum optio sint expedita modi atque esse exercitationem assumenda quasi nostrum corrupti obcaecati, culpa ea ipsa. Delectus, eum, repellat.</p>
  <p>Reiciendis debitis doloribus aliquam nesciunt dolorem repellendus. Iste, ducimus. Nostrum necessitatibus soluta, impedit laborum quam eaque accusamus error illo iste reiciendis, veniam facilis repudiandae! Iste, accusantium autem corrupti magnam aut!</p>
</div>
```

**Logic /  Explanation:**

The basic HTML structure is the following:

> body > #cover + #body

where #cover is the loading placeholder and #body is a div which contains all your content. By default, #cover is covering the entire viewport and #body has a top offset. After loading, #cover is moved up by negative top offset and #body slides up by removing the negative offset.

For demonstration sake, I made the effect show on click. The changes rely on CSS `transition` that change top offset by class toggle instead of JavaScript/jQuery slide function.

In your case, the loading code would be:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    Pace.on('done', function() {
    $("body").addClass("slideup");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Aziz, this is almost working, just the cover is disappearing without scrolling up, I'll try t fix that.

Comment: Did you add `transition:.3s;` to it? Also make sure to add any vendor prefixes, if needed.

Comment: That's strange, would appreciate a live demo to debug it properly and find what's causing this.

Comment: I tried both solution but they do not work properly on my website, maybe cause I have too many elements with different positionings. I kept the fade out solution by now :) Thanks so much, BTW. Fed.

Comment: @FedericoFerrari I wouldn't mind troubleshooting this with you, come to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104752/azizs-room

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are using `position: fixed`, just place `#cover` element the first element of page and add body class wtih `overflow: hidden` property, and after `slideUp()` is finished remove class.
Hope this helps see: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89fgu4g3/6/)

## Edited:

Here is approach with `#cover` sliding up and content follows: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89fgu4g3/9/)

Comment: Interesting, not sure if OP wants the #cover to shrink in height or to actually MOVE upside off the screen..

Comment: Thanks @jjanko3 I tried but this solution isn't working.

The body already has a class .pace-running (when the loader is running, obviously) and a class .pace-done (when it reaches 100%) if that's help.

Comment: @Aziz I actually want to cover to move up, off the screen, that's right.
If you see the example website you understand perfectly.